# VB2008 How to use common name inside private sub (similar this.value in javascript)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, this

I would like to know is there any way to type component in common name in VB2008. See the below example.

```
 Private Sub ComboBox3_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.GotFocus
    Dim get_current As String
    get_current = ComboBox3.Text
    ComboBox3.DataSource = GetMailItems("default_values", "nationality")
    ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "Name"
    ComboBox3.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox3.Text = get_current
End Sub
```

You can see how many times I typed ComboBox3.
When I copy this to other ComboBox_GotFocus inside, I have to change all ComboBox3 --> Combobox4.

Is there anyway I can use it like **this.DisplayMember = "Name"** (similar to javascript code) You can see javascript code example below.

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title)" >
<option title="first">first</option>  
<option title="second">second</option>
</select>
```

Thank You,

Sameera Silva

Comment: With...End With Statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But in javascript, we don't have to specify element even one time. But if we use with statement, we have to specify element name at the beginning.

Comment: `When I copy this to other ComboBox_GotFocus inside, I have to change all ComboBox3 --> Combobox4.` Consider handling several comboboxes GotFocus event in single event handler. sender is combobox that initiates the event. BTW, don't expect from VB exactly the same features as in javascript. VB is not scripting language.

Comment: If there is no way... With...End With I can use.. anyway thank you very much for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Options:

1 - use the `With` Keyword:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.GotFocus
    With ComboBox3
        .DisplayMember = "Name"
        .ValueMember = "ID"
        .Text = get_current
    End With
End Sub
```

2 - Use the `Sender` argument

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox3.GotFocus
    Dim cb = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    cb.DisplayMember = "Name"
    cb.ValueMember = "ID"
    cb.Text = get_current
End Sub
```

3 - If you use the same code in other combo box gotfocus events you can combine number 2 to handle more than one boxes event:

```
Private Sub AllCombos_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
                               Handles ComboBox1.GotFocus, ComboBox2.GotFocus, ComboBox3.GotFocus
    Dim cb = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    cb.DisplayMember = "Name"
    cb.ValueMember = "ID"
    cb.Text = get_current
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, Its great I like the way you use 2nd option and 3rd option.